# why does setting primary output doesn't appear in creating setup in vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a setup for my application, but I cannot set primary output because it does not have value. These are the steps I have made so far.

enter image description here[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your installer project is in the same solution with the project that you want to create a installer.